# How to use Round function in informix (12.10) view

Tags: function, rounding, informix

need to use the round function in one of my views to round the numeric value column. but when I try to save it's showing syntax error.Please help me

[Round function implemented in my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpzO2.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of text.  Add the text to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the ROUND function but the CREATE VIEW syntax.

You have:

```
CREATE VIEW AS test1234 SELECT …
```

You need:

```
CREATE VIEW test1234 AS SELECT …
```